# How to use ajax jquery function in order to pass string url and data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this ajax jquery function:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/Member/SaveCoordinates/@Model.Id',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: window.image.pinpoints,
                    success: function (data) {

                       alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {

                        alert("error");
                    }
                });


                return false;
            });
```

Here is my controller:

```
public string SaveCoordinates(string Id, object[] pFrame) 
{
     do something...
}
```

I want to be able to pass the string id in the url and then also pass the object window.image.pinpoints.  The id doesnt HAVE to be passed through the url, thats just the way I was doing it normally.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this be a GET method? your POST method has no parameters passed. 
your ajax url should be something like this (thats how your controller is defined):
/Member/SaveCoordinates/@Model.Id/@pframe

or

controller (assuming you are using php): 
public string SaveCoordinates(string Id, object[] pFrame=null) {
   print log here so you know your ajax call reached your controller
}